# std::uniform_real_distribution cannot be const anymore in MSVS2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

In MSVS 2019 I used to declare my distribution `const`. Yet in the latest MSVS2022 preview, I get an error:

```
error C3848: expression having type 'const std::uniform_real_distribution<double>' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'double std::uniform_real<_Ty>::operator ()<std::mt19937>(_Engine &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=double,
1>            _Engine=std::mt19937
1>        ]
```

If I strip the `const` all is fine again. Is this a MSVS2022 quirk? Or was 2019 wrong all that time?
(example from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    const std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1.0, 2.0); // this const will break in MSVS2022
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        // Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into a 
        // double in [1, 2). Each call to dis(gen) generates a new random double
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `uniform_real_distribution<T>::operator()` is not a `const` member function, and never was.

Comment: Compiles (when it should not) in v19.21 - live - https://godbolt.org/z/eqsE9oEh8 . Correctly fails to compile in v19.latest - live - https://godbolt.org/z/PWK5Eezse .  Looks like a MS bug fix has caught you out.

Comment: Bug fix: [<random>: distribution::operator() is erroneously const #1912](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1912) .  _"...std::uniform_int_distribution::operator() and operator() of other distributions like uniform_real_distribution and geometric_distribution are all const, while the standard does not specify that these are const. This poses a portability problem for code marking the distribution as const to other standard libraries in which the operator is not const...."_

Comment: Sigh. Two out of three comments are utterly wrong, despite getting the most upvotes (at the moment). There is **no requirement** that `operator()` not be `const`. See the answer by user17732522.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`const std::uniform_real_distribution<>` was never guaranteed to be usable. The standard did not specify that `operator()` of `std::uniform_real_distribution` is `const`. In particular `<random>`'s distributions are allowed to have internal state, e.g. to remember unused bits returned from the generator or to store state if the transformation algorithm requires it.

However, standard library implementations are allowed to add `const` on a non-virtual member function if that wouldn't affect any call to the function that would be well-formed without it according to the standard's specification. Therefore Microsoft's implementation was not non-conforming in allowing you to use the `const` version, even if that is not guaranteed to work according to the standard.

Nonetheless Microsoft's standard library developers decided to remove the `const` by-default anyway, to encourage portability with other standard library implementations. They left the option to define `_ALLOW_RANDOM_DISTRIBUTION_CONST_OPERATOR` (e.g. on the command line `/D_ALLOW_RANDOM_DISTRIBUTION_CONST_OPERATOR`) to get back the old non-portable behavior if someone really needs it.

All of this is explained and discussed in the corresponding issue https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1912 and the pull request https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/2732.